# Dealing with BACKSLASH character in non-string literals in Python

Tags: python, string, encoding, escaping

I have the following string read from an XML elememnt, and it is assigned to a variable called filename. *I don't know how to make this any clearer as saying filename = the following string, without leading someone to think that I have a string literal then.*

```
\\server\data\uploads\0224.1307.Varallo.mov
```

when I try and pass this to

```
os.path.basename(filename)
```

I get the following

```
\\server\\data\\uploads\x124.1307.Varallo.mov
```

I tried filename.replace('\\','\\\\') but that doesn't work either. os.path.basename(filename) then returns the following.

```
\\\\server\\data\\uploads\\0224.1307.Varallo.mov
```

Notice that the \0 is now not being converted to \x but now it doesn't process the string at all.

what can I do to my filename variable to get this String in a proper state so that os.path.basename() will actually give me back the basename. I am on OSX so the uncpath stuff is not available.

All attempts to replace the \ with \\ manually fail because of the \0 getting converted to \x in the beginning of the basename.

**NOTE: this is NOT a string literal so r'' doesn't work.**

Comment: It's not particularly clear what your problem is. The backslashes seem to be escaped correctly...

Comment: We need more information. What exactly is in the variable filename? To answer, use `print repr(filename)` and add the results to your question above.

Comment: Backslashes in non-literal strings are just backslashes. Nothing special about them. If that's the exact string you have, it's equivalent to the string literal `"\\\\server\\data\\uploads\\0224.1307.Varallo.mov"`.

Comment: no they are not os.path.basename() is converting the \0 to \x as per my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need more information. What exactly is in the variable filename? To answer, use `print repr(filename)` and add the results to your question above.

---

**Wild guess**

DISCLAIMER: This is a guess - try:

```
import ntpath
print ntpath.basename(filename)
```

Comment: This is the syntax for a windows file share, so the windows path module still should be used. Using ntpath works just fine on Mac and does what you want: typing `ntpath.basename(r'\\server\data\uploads\0224.1307.Varallo.mov')` gives `0224.1307.Varallo.mov` as expected.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop, the ntpath module exists on OSX and is exactly what you need to deal with UNC paths. Did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

All the downvoting in the world won't change the fact that **you're doing it wrong**. `os.path` is for native paths. `\\foo\bar\baz` is not a OS X path, it's a Windows UNC. `posixpath` is not equipped to handle UNCs; `ntpath` is.